# An article with an adjective modifying a name

Tags: articles

If I want to describe someone with an adjective do I need an article?

> 1 He is angry Steve. or He is an angry Steve. or He is the angry
> Steve.
>
> 2 He is angry Steve now. or He is an angry Steve now. or He is the
> angry Steve now.
>
> 3 I am hungry Maria. or I am a hungry Maria. or I am the hungry Maria.
>
> 4 I am hungry Maria now. or I am a hungry Maria now. or I am the
> hungry Maria now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very unusual sentence structure. You wouldn't normally use an adjective on a name like in your examples except as a comical way of referring to a large change in character or to differentiate between a group of people with the same name.

For example, "hungry Maria" sounds like Maria changes her personality enough when she is hungry to be humourously referred to as if she was a different person with the name Hungry Maria. If this is the meaning and context you are looking for then it is correct to have no article.

"An angry Steve" or "The angry Steve" would only be used if you had a group of people named Steve and needed to refer specifically to the one that is angry.

For simply referring to the fact that Maria is hungry, it is better to use something like "Maria is hungry now"

Comment: "Maria is hungry now" is out of question as it's clear. What if I want to describe myself. Should it be "I am a/the/- hungry Maria now!" Plus this: "It was all very well to say `Drink me,' but the wise little Alice was not going to do THAT in a hurry." Why "the wise little Alice"?

Comment: That usage was acceptable in a 19th century story, but it would not be natural to use it in everyday conversation.

Comment: If you are describing yourself, you could simply say "I am hungry now". It is not common to refer to yourself by name in normal conversation except for humurous effect (even this is rare) such as in the contexts I provided. As Kate Bunting said, the example you have given is very literary in nature and would likely sound strange in everyday speech.

Comment: So, you would say like this? "It was all very well to say `Drink me,' but wise little Alice was not going to do THAT in a hurry."

Comment: ededededed87, I think you understand that "I am hungry now" is out of the scope of this question. The whole idea is to include a name. I know it's not a very common way to speak but it's a possible way.

Comment: The issue is that you are combining an old literature 3rd person style with an unusual way to refer to yourself. (Note that Alice in Wonderland is written in 3rd person so the author is not referring to themselves). It could make sense to use one or the other but by combining them you are mixing 2 unusual styles and it starts to sound strange.  The only way I can think of making this work would be if you were speaking as if you were narrating a story about your self or in the way I described using "Hungry Maria" in my answer. All of these examples use unusual language for the purpose of humour

Comment: Alice doesn't sound so old, by the way. OK let's leave along 1st person. Do you claim that it should be written without THE ""It was all very well to say `Drink me,' but (NO THE) wise little Alice was not going to do THAT in a hurry."

Comment: The sentence from Alice in Wonderland works as it is (with the 'the') because it is referring to Alice in the 3rd person and as part of the narration of a story (and using a literary style). If you try to apply this structure to referring to yourself or for use in everyday speech, you may encounter problems.